# Why are my "Ignored" tags showing on mobile?

Tags: bug, status-declined, ignored-tags, stackexchange-mobile-app

I have no particular interest in seeing any Minecraft questions, so I used the `*` wildcard to ignore any and all Minecraft related questions.

While browsing Arqade via the web, everything looks as is should
[image]

Unfortunately this does not reflect in mobile. As shown below, there is a Minecraft question that does not show up in the browser.

[image]

Is this a bug of some sort?

Comment: Can I clarify: by "mobile" do you mean the mobile *app* (and if so: which OS)? Or do you mean the website when accessed through a mobile device?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, I am using the mobile app; running *Android OS, v6.0.1*. I apologize for the confusion

Comment: Can verify your issue on my end as well, running Android 6.0.1. Ignored tags still appear on mobile.

Comment: On iOS, they show up, but are greyed out. I think that is just how it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The Stack Exchange Mobile Apps are [no longer actively maintained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/179041), and [similar requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/179041) for fixes have been declined as such.

The (majority of) the mobile APIs are still active and will remain in place for the time being, [so long as they're low maintenance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363043/179041), so if you still actively use the app, or use programs or tools that rely on the mobile API, they will continue to work in their current state for the time being.